# Doinbackground sometimes never finish on json response?

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-asynctask

I have a problem in my code. Sometimes when i have a poor internet connection the device detect that i have internet, so when I open the activity, I execute this Asynctask:

```
class Something extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this){
            @Override
            public void onBackPressed() {
                pDialog.cancel();
                pDialog.dismiss();
                esCancelado=true;
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PrincipalMenu.class);

                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        };
        pDialog.setMessage("Cargando. Por favor espere...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Obtenemos el string del JSON desde la URL
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = JSONParser.readJsonFromUrl(url);
        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            // Verifica que se cargaron datos
            int success;
            if(json == null){
                success = 0;
            }
            else {
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            }

            if (success == 1) {// Se encontraron complejos
                //do something
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //do something
            }
        });
}
```

The problem is in this line I think (Only happen in my college where I have a poor internet connection and I don't have the computer to see where is the problem):

```
json = JSONParser.readJsonFromUrl(url);
```

Doinbackground sometimes no finish (because the dialog still loading and never dismiss), and if I go back and try again the activity i have the same problem  (no matter if my internet connection go back) so I have to force close the app and restart it and when I try again the thread works correctly (if I have a good internet connection). I don't know if is something with the internet cache or not.

This is my parser class:

```
package com.sourcey.modeloUsuarios;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class JSONParser {

public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    try  {
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        String jsonText = readAll(rd);
        return new JSONObject(jsonText);
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
}

private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
        sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

}
```

Thanks for helping me! Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you try adding a Countdown timer, to count down for 10 seconds (or whatever time you want) , and if by that time the AsyncTask didn't finish (check this by setting a bool variable in `onPostExecute()` to true) you just cancel this task: `mTask.cancel(true);`

Comment: I'm guessing that you have this problem since the first AsyncTask never finishes, something messes it up when the internet is slow. Just kill it after some time.